# How can I route a call to a staticmethod via a decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Minimum Python version: Python 3.7

I'm working on some code to encode/decode a model from a versioned json/yaml schema. I'm looking for a clean way to implement this that isn't a tonne of massive if-elif-else chains that test for schema version.

So, given something like:

```
class SchemaVersion(Enum):
    v1 = "2020-10-15"
    v2 = "2021-07-06"
    v3 = "2022-01-10"
    ... etc
```

I am currently writing code that looks like:

```
class Decodable(ABC, Generic[T]]):
    @abstractmethod
    @staticmethod
    def decode(*, version: SchemaVersion, model: Dict[str, Any]) -> T:
        # Factory pattern
        # Decode a model given as dictionaries as per the schema version
        pass

class Example(Decodable["Example"], Encodable)
    @staticmethod
    def decode(*, version: SchemaVersion, model: Dict[str, Any]) -> Example:
        if version in (SchemaVersion.v1,SchemaVersion.v2):
            ... decode model using schema v1 (which is the same as v2 for this model)
        elif version in (SchemaVersion.v3,):
            ... decode model using schema v3
        else:
            raise RuntimeError(...)
```

I can see where this is going with the implementations of decode and encode being massive if/elif/else chains as more revisions to the schema are added.

I'd love to be able to decorate methods in the model class so that a generic `decode()` staticmethod on the base class can route to the appropriate decoder staticmethod in the derived class based on the schema version being decoded. Is this possible? How?

For example:

```
class Decodable:
    @staticmethod
    def decode(*, version: SchemaVersion, mdoel: Dict[str, Any]) -> Decodable:
        ... select the derived-class method decorated to decode the schema version and run it


class Example(Decodable, Encodable):
    @decodes(SpecificationVersion.v1)
    @decodes(SpecificationVersion.v2)
    def _decode_0(*, version: SchemaVersion, model: Dict[str, Any]) -> Example:
        .. decode. Note: schema v1 is the same as v2 for this model
    
    @decodes(SpecificationVersion.v3)
    def _decode_1(*, version: SchemaVersion, model: Dict[str, Any]) -> Example:
        ... decode
```

So, calling `Example.decode(version=SchemaVersion.v1, model=...)` results in `Example._decode_0(version=SchemaVersion.v1, model=...)`  being called.

Thank you!

Comment: By *(a) it's even possible, and (b) how to pull it off.* you mean is to decorate that way?

Comment: @sudden_appearance Yes. To elaborate... what would the code for the decorator, `Decodable.decode`, and `Encodable.encode` even look like if it were possible.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask, and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*. We don't deal in "suggestions" here, but in objective, clear, specific *questions*; and we aren't interested in any particular person's skills or qualifications, only the correctness of answers.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Point taken.

Comment: The massive if-else chain can be avoided by simply defining separate methods for each version. (The methods should probably be class methods, too, not static methods.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer you want to know i guess is the parametrized decorator
It is built as follows:

```
def decodes(versions: List[SpecificationSchema]):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(self, version, *args, **kwargs):
            # you can add and then update if already exist a hidden dict
            # which will map a version to a callable function
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Usage will be

```
@decodes([SpecificationSchema.v1, SpecificationSchema.v2])
def decoder_1(...):
    ...
```

and if you make a dict with mapping a callable, then decode will be something like this

```
def decode(version, ...):
    return self.decode_for_version[version]()
```

Comment: Also notice, `self` inside a wrapper will represent a object (`self` parameter of a decorator function). You do not pass it when using `instance.method(*args)`, but do pass when use decorators. So, you will have an access to a object inside a decorator. You can also change it to classmethod and use `cls` as a variable identifier instead.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, then that doesn't seem quite right based on the quick experiment that I tried.  `wrapper()` is only called if `decoder_1()` is explicitly called, but the intent is for `decoder_1()` to only be called by `decode()`.  So, nothing done in `wrapper()` to add/update a hidden dict will ever happen before `decode()` is called.

Comment: Oh, that's true. My fault.

Comment: I genuinely appreciate the attempt, though. I do understand decorators a little bit more as a result of it.